# Jquery trigger click with valueChangeListener on tr:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jquery, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I am facing one issue with trinidad selectManyCheckbox

```
<tr:selectManyCheckbox  immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{EmployeeBean.valueChangeUser}" autoSubmit="true" id="abc" >

<f:selectItem  itemLabel="Option1" onclick="return false;" itemValue="first" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" itemValue="Second"/>   
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" itemValue="Third"/>   
 </tr:selectManyCheckbox>
```

When I am using valueChangeListener in this component I am not able to clicked the selectItem through jquyery trigger click. After removing valueChangeListener  I am able to check  the checkbox jquery trigger click . Any idea why jquery trigger click is not working with valueChangeListener

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Simple click function with plain javascript is working fine